# Adding a changing image to homepage

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, dynamic

Hey guys I'm designing a website for my mothers backpackers business and currently I have set up a basic template for my webpages. On my homepage I am wanting to have an image that cycles through about 3 or 4 photos.

For example like this webpage here: http://www.qsb.co.nz/

What is the best way to go about doing this? I noticed in the markup it said it was a javascript? I'm at the end of my second year studying CS at uni so I can code in java and C - is this much different?

How would I go about:

1. Coding a script to cycle through 3 or 4 images. Which language / technique is best?
2. Including this script in my webpage.

Thanks in advance for your answers guys this website has been very very helpful so far.

Comment: http://jquery.com/ + http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Answer (score 2):

Wesley Murch is right - jQuery (a Javascript framework) is the best recommended way to accomplish what you want.

I would recommend either ppshein's link or Medien Fruede's innerFade:
http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/